# CS1519: Invalid token '<' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-1.1

I have an aspx page with the following method in it:

```
public List<AutoCardTable> populateTable()
{
    return populateTable(null, null, null, null);
}
```

which works fine on my local machine.

However, when I put it on the server, I get the following error:

```
CS1519: Invalid token '<' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
```

Which, form what I can tell, is telling me that the character

```
<
```

is not valid in this method declaration.

But why not? or is it really something else? Why would it work on my local but not on the server? Possibly some .net 1.1 interacting with this, but I still do not think this would cause this problem?

I cannot find any examples on google of a problem with this character.

I am totally stumped - any ideas?

Comment: In ASP.NET 1.1. there were no generics. You can't use that code in a .NET version lower than 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET 1.1 doesn't support generics. Unless you can update to 2.0 (preferrably 3.5), you'll have to do without (in this case, using either your own class or `ArrayList` instead of `List<...>`). You should also make sure your local development environment actually uses .NET 1.1 (which may be tricky, to say the least).